# PowerShell - How to specify ContentType when using Invoke-RestMethod to upload file

Tags: powershell

Using Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod in powershell 7, how do I set the ContentType of files posted files in form data?

The issue I am having is the receiving application can see the expected fields and files, but the ContentType for the file is application/octet-stream instead of application/zip

```
Basic code:
    $fields = @{
      rType = "myType"
      rVersion = "version"
      rClient = "client"
      rFile = Get-Item -Path "path to .zip file"
    }
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Form $fields
```

The -ContentType option of Invoke-WebRequest is ignored when using -Form

Comment: hello matt, please check the answer below and mark it as `Answer` if it solved your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the content type using `-ContentType` i.e.

```
$type = 'application/octet-stream'
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Form $fields -ContentType $type
```

please check Microsoft documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: ContentType is overridden to multipart/form-data when using -Form.